# Размер указателя на функцию

Tags: c++

Пусть имеется банальный код:

```
void foo(){}

int main(){
std::cout << foo;
}
```

Вывод на консоль: 1.
Я не понимаю почему так, ведь foo в данном случае функция и должна вывести адрес, который уж точно не равен единице.

Comment: В данном случает foo каститься к bool типу

Comment: То есть? Что её кастит?

Comment: Ничто ее не кастит, размер `void == 1`. Если хотите получить адрес, то вам чтоит завести переменную с указателем, а получить размер указателя `std::cout << sizeof(&foo);` А скорее всего оптимизатор выкидывает вашу функцию в которой ничего нет.

Comment: @LLENN "размер void == 1" - ничего подобного, `void` - это неполный тип у которого отсутствует размер. "оптимизатор выкидывает вашу функцию" - тоже не соответствует действительности

Comment: @Сергей Терпеливый: Ее "кастит" неявное преобразование. Когда оператора нет, выбирается самый подходящий. В данном случае самым подходящим оказался `bool`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Перегрузки оператора `<<` для вывода адреса функций нет. Зато есть перегрузка для вывода `bool`. Соответственно адрес функции неявно преобразуется в `bool`. Вывести значение адреса можно явно преобразовав указатель на функцию к указателю на `void` (перегрузка оператора `<<` для которого как раз печатает значение адреса):

```
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void *>(&foo);
```

Comment: Премного благодарен. И ещё, используя ваш код вывод на консоль я получил следующий: 0x555c3f940b8a. Тут как видно 6 байт, однако sizeof показывает 8. И ещё, если операционная система 64 битная, то указатели будут не 4 байта размером, а 8, я прав?

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый В этом случае не выводятся ведущие нули. Если приложение 64 битное - то да, 8 байт

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Наверное, стоит отметить, что преобразование указателя на функцию в указатель на void поддерживается В C++ лишь условно.

Comment: А не может ли оказаться так, что указатель на функцию имеет размер, отичный от `void*`?

Comment: @Mikhailo Вообще-то может, но разве что на экзотичеких плфтформах

Comment: @Mikhailo "А не может ли оказаться так, что указатель на функцию имеет размер, отличный от void*?" - на x86/amd64 и ARM все указатели имеют одинаковый размер, так как по своей сути указывают просто на ячейку памяти. И неважно что за тип указателя - на переменную, на экземпляр класса или на функцию.

Comment: Указатель на метод экземпляра больше.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, что товарищ @user7860670 ошибается. Фраза *"Перегрузки оператора << для вывода адреса функций нет"*, по всей видимости, некорректна. Правильно было бы сказать, что **перегрузки оператора << для вывода указателя на функцию нет**. А нет этой перегрузки из-за того, что у функции может быть совершенно произвольный прототип (разное количество и тип параметров, разный тип возвращаемого значения), а следовательно и тип указателя на функцию может быть совершенно произвольным.

Далее нужно понять, почему указатель на функцию кастится в bool, а не в const void* или не в unsigned long и не в что-нибудь еще.

Пока что мое предположение состоит в том, что каст в bool происходит потому, что это указатель (неважно на что), и автоматическое разрешение типа указателя срабатывает именно на bool, потому что это первый подходящий прототип в стандарте C++ в описании класса std::basic_ostream:

```
// 29.7.5.1 Class template basic_ostream [ostream]
namespace std {
  template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>>
  class basic_ostream : virtual public basic_ios<charT, traits> {
  
public:
...

  // 29.7.5.2, formatted output
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
  operator<<(basic_ostream<charT, traits>& (*pf)(basic_ostream<charT, traits>&));
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
  operator<<(basic_ios<charT, traits>& (*pf)(basic_ios<charT, traits>&));
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>&
  operator<<(ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&));

  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(bool n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(short n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(unsigned short n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(int n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(unsigned int n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(long n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(unsigned long n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(long long n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(unsigned long long n);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(float f);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(double f);
  basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(long double f);
```

Я могу ошибаться, возможно будет более правильный ответ.

Comment: Существует неявное преобразование из указателя на функцию в `bool`, но нет неявного преобразования из указателя на функцию в `const void*`. Вот почему в качестве подходящего оператора `operator<<` выбирается именно принимающий параметр `bool`, а не `const void*`. И именно из-за отсутствия неявного преобразования используется явный каст в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981143): `reinterpret_cast<void *>(&foo)`. Порядок объявления прототипов роли не играет. Если есть два одинаково подходящих прототипа, то программа просто не скомпилируется.